# The MongoDB PECL extension has not been installed or enabled php7.0 codeigniter cimongo library ubuntu16.04

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter

I am trying to use CIMongo Library for codeigniter to use php and mongo
But I am getting err:The MongoDB PECL extension has not been installed or enabled
But I installed everything correctly
- pecl install mongodb
    apt-get install php-mongodb

Will be greatful for any help
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

For the windows users who end up here after googling "The MongoDB PECL extension has not been installed or enabled". (May be other OS users having the same issue also can grab some clues from here):

First of all thanks [simon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4681654/simon) for his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38767062/1425779)

Previous codeigniter versions used the php_mongo.dll ([mongo pecl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mongo.php)) which you can download from [here](http://pecl.php.net/package/mongo)

Below is how earlier versions check for the existence of the Mongo extension.

```
if(!class_exists('Mongo'))
{
    $this->_show_error('The MongoDB PECL extension has not been installed or enabled', 500);
}
```

But newer codeigniter version looks for php_mongodb.dll ([mongodb pecl](http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php)) which is you can download from [here](http://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb)

Below is how newer versions check for the existence of the Mongo extension.

```
if (!class_exists('MongoDB\Driver\Manager')) {
   show_error("The MongoDB PECL extension has not been installed or enabled", 500);
}
```

Comment: I don't exactly know why I got this error but after I deleted and regenerated by `composer.lock` file the error was resolved

Answer (score 0):

i had also got this error..
I use Bellow sollution, that works for me.

https://servertroubles.blogspot.in/2012/05/configuring-mongodb-from-php-and-xampp.html?showComment=1475216457950#c4755324682340768979

Comment: This answer is only available for Windows users.
I would like some help, I'm currently facing the same PECL error, I'm using Debian with NGINX, PHP7 and CI 3.x