# Fatal error: Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found

Tags: php, mongodb

I want to use the MongoDB Driver, but it throw me an error, when i use it:

```
$mongo = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
```

The error:

> Message: Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found

When i check it with the php_info(), i see, there is [image]

Is there any requirement to use the driver?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25660534/386579

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is some confusion between the Mongo extension and the MongoDB extension which are not the same. Because of your version number, I guess you are using the old Mongo extension that is *deprecated*.

Make sure that you install the new [MongoDB extension](http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php) and you should be fine. Don't forget to remove the old `extension=mongo.so` from your php.ini since this could cause problems.

Comment: For windows users find the php_mongodb.dll in http://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb

Answer (score 18):

For me, I forgot to add `extension=mongodb.so` to the `php.ini` for FPM (FastCGI Process Manager). On Ubuntu 16.04 this was at:

`/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini`

For what it's worth I'm using nginx.

Comment: Worked perfectly.

Comment: thats the trick

Answer (score 10):

1.Add mongo DB

```
$sudo apt update && sudo apt install php-mongodb
```

2. Restart  apache server,
3. check in phpinfo() for mongo

Answer (score 8):

How to install on macOS Mojave

Start with:

```
sudo pecl install mongodb
```

To check if mongodb package is installed, look for "mongodb" when you run:

```
pecl list
```

To get your installed mongodb.so path, run:

```
pecl list-files mongodb | grep mongodb.so
```

then remove (or comment out) on your php.ini file:

```
extension="mongodb.so"
```

(I could not found a line with extension="php_mongodb.so")

now insert a line with:

```
extension="{{the path to your installed mongodb.so}}"
```

Run this command to get your `ext-*.ini` directory path:

```
php -i | grep Scan
```

Create your ext-mongodb.ini with:

```
touch {{your conf.d path}}/ext-mongodb.ini
```

like:

```
touch /usr/local/etc/php/7.1/conf.d/ext-mongodb.ini
```

Restart your apache to read the new configuration

Sanity check with:

```
php -i | grep mongodb
```

You're ready to go.

Answer (score 4):

If you get this error, even after you installed the Mongodb driver for php, just install mongodb using composer.

```
composer require mongodb/mongodb
```

After that this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This error is because of `php_mongodb.dll` file is missing in the etc folder and add to the `php.ini` file like`(extension=php_mongodb.dll)` . Because of this I got this error. It will rectify my error

Answer (score 1):

With the new version of centos, editing `php.ini` does not work anymore,

You need to add the `mongodb.ini` file with the content `extension=mongodb.so` in the `etc/php.d` folder

Then don't forget to restart php-fpm: `sudo systemctl restart php-fpm.service`

Answer (score 0):

Might be your CLI version of php is different ,check php version  in terminal using php -v.
and then switch accordingly...
FOR EX-:

From PHP 7.1 => PHP 5.6

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php5.6.
```

I hope it will help you guys.