# Php MongoDB, Fatal error: Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found in

Tags: php, mongodb

[image for mongo info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6D1iw.png)

MongoDB shell version v3.4.1

mongodb driver v1.6.14

xampp v3.2.1, Apache/2.4.16 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1p PHP/5.6.12

i m running for first time and getting this problem plz help me.

Fatal error: Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found in H:\xampp\htdocs\www\phpmongodb\vendor\mongodb\mongodb\src\Client.php on line 81

Comment: Is file exist in: H:\xampp\htdocs\www\phpmongodb\vendor\mongodb\mongodb\src\?

Comment: yes it is there....!

Comment: It can be issue in auto-loader.. do you use composer ?

Comment: [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38766586/fatal-error-class-mongodb-driver-manager-not-found) same question...

Comment: thankx for concern problem was with php driver configuration

Comment: @iramch Could you specify what exactly you did to make it work again? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error before I set up the mongodb added the following link to **'vendor/autoload.php'**. In many cases you need to check your hosting. It started working after my code looked like the following:

```
  $DB_CONNECTION_STRING="mongodb://YourCredentials";
  require '../../vendor/autoload.php';
  $manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager( $DB_CONNECTION_STRING );
```

Then if you use MongoDB\Driver\Manager, a modern version of MongoDB driver, you have something looks such as this:

***Create** a document in the collection*:

```
$bulkWrite = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;
$doc = ['name' => 'John', age => 33, profession => 'Guess what?'];
$bulkWrite->insert($doc);
$manager->executeBulkWrite('db.MyCollection', $bulkWrite);
```

***Read** document in the collection* by name with a limit:

```
$filter = ['name' => 'John'];
$options = ['limit' => 2];
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);
$manager->executeQuery('db.MyCollection', $query);
```

***Read** document in the collection* by MongoDb _id with a limit:

```
$filter = ['_id' => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID( '5bdf54e6d722dc000f0aa6c2' )];
$options = ['limit' => 2];
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);
$manager->executeQuery('db.MyCollection', $query);
```

***Update** document in the collection*:  (Read more about options upsert and multi [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb-driver-bulkwrite.update.php))

```
$bulkWrite = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;
$filter = ['name' => 'John'];
$update = ['$set' => ['name' => 'Smith', age: 35, profession => 'Guess what?']];
$options = ['multi' => false, 'upsert' => false];
$bulkWrite->update($filter, $update, $options);
$manager->executeBulkWrite('db.MyCollection', $bulkWrite);
```

***Delete** document in the collection - Delete*:

```
$bulkWrite = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;
$filter = ['name' => 'John', age => 35];
$options = ['limit' => 1];
$bulkWrite->delete($filter, $options);
$manager->executeBulkWrite('db.MyCollection', $bulkWrite);
```