# Uncaught Error: Class "MongoDB\Driver\Manager" not found

Tags: php, wordpress, mongodb, wordpress-plugin-creation

I'm having an issue with a Wordpress plugin that i created.
The plugin is supposed to connect to my mongodb atlas database and compare all the document's contents to the users form inputs, But when i upload and activate the plugin i get this Error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "MongoDB\Driver\Manager" not found in C:\...\vendor\mongodb\mongodb\src\Client.php:126
```

The error is triggered in the mongodb connection string line

```
$mongoClient = new MongoDB\Client('mongodb+srv://XXXX:XXXX@cluster0.XXXX.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority');
```

on my php file and is due to 'Manager' not being defined in `'C:\...\vendor\mongodb\mongodb\src\Client.php'` 
I tried to import the class using `use MongoDB\Driver\Manager;` but it didn't work.
There's the line : `

```
$this->manager = new Manager($uri, $uriOptions, $driverOptions);
```

NB: I've already installed and configured the **mongodb php driver** and the the library **mongodb library**.
The Plugin works fine when i run it locally, but i get this error when i upload it and activate it on wordpress.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fatal error: Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38766586/fatal-error-class-mongodb-driver-manager-not-found)

Comment: Thanks for replying. I already tried that but i didnt work neither. The workaroud that i found is to install mongodb and the application on another instance and call it in wordpress wich worked fine.