# Class "MongoDB\Driver\Manager" not found

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, xampp

My PHP version is 8.2.4
My Laravel version is 10.10
i am using xampp.
the issue is because of the php extention of mongodb in my xampp.
i can not be able to have any extensions for mongodb.
can anyone help me to solve this issue.

I have tried coping mongodb.dll file but still its not working

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38766586/fatal-error-class-mongodb-driver-manager-not-found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Issue is solved,

The solution is to get the particular version of Mongodb dll file from **[Github Releases](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/releases/)** and then copy the dll file to the desired location of xampp's ext folder.

Example:

My PHP Version is 8.2.4, so I need to download the Mongodb dll file which will support php 8.2.4 version which is **{php_mongodb-1.15.0-8.2-ts-x64.zip} (extension_name-extension_version-php_version-windows_bit)**

After downloading, extract the zip file anywhere on the pc.

Then copy the **php_mongodb.dll** and **php_mongodb.pdb** file to the xampp ext folder for me it is **C:\xampp\php\ext**

After that add **extension=php_mongodb.dll** in **php.ini** file.

Finally, restart the xampp apache the extension will be installed.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A "class not found" message is not an issue of php, instead of missing mongodb library which you can install with composer: https://github.com/mongodb/laravel-mongodb.
Then if you have other issues caused by missing driver you will see a different error.